# String To TextBox id

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using asp.net 2.0 i need help for string Value to Textbox id..I am already declare textbox in source that id in string value..i have more than ten textbox.but textbox id serial number i set value all text box same time same value i use below code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    String _control = "txt_capex_" + i.ToString().Trim();
    TextBox txt = FindControl(_control) as TextBox;
    txt.Text = _splitamount.ToString().Trim();
}
```

i get Error in

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>     Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

what solution for this..

Comment: I'm guessing `FindControl` returns null?

Comment: I think that FindControl method fails. It's there where you get the nullReference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Did you set the names on the TextBoxes?

Comment: And for reference if you're using the `as` keyword, it means you believe there's a possibility it won't be the requested type. You should really be handling that case.

Comment: yes return null value..

Comment: Can you show where in the markup are these text boxes declared or inserted?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txt_capex_1" runat="server" Width="40px" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Ok, so why won't `txt_capex_1.Text = "foo";` work?!

Answer (score 1):

Is it fair to assume all of your textboxes aren't lying on the page itself? That is, you probably have some nested in `Panel`s, `GridView`s, or other similar controls. Particularly if you're adding them dynamically, which I assume you are. Make sure you're calling the parent's `FindControl` method, not just the page's.

[`Page.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method searches only the page's immediate, or top-level, container; it does not recursively search for controls in naming containers contained on the page. To access controls in a subordinate naming container, call the FindControl method of that container.

The other possibility is that you're casting to the wrong type. Because you're using the `as` keyword as compared to conventional `(Type)value` casting, that expression will resolve to null if the `FindControl` method returns anything that can't be assigned to a `TextBox` value, as compared to the traditional throwing of an exception.

Comment: TextBox txt = FindControl(_control) as TextBox (or)TextBox txt = (TextBox)FindControl(_control); both Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Yes, I figured. I very much expect that it's a matter of mistaking the `TextBox`'s parent.

Answer (score 0):

either FindControl or _splitamount return NullReferenceException.Please debug your code.also if possible can you please put StackTrace of your error here ?

Comment: at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="App_Web_-di-a3lt"

Comment: it clears that your FindControl() could not find proper control.

Comment: can you please tell me do you want dynamic generation of Textbox or finding Textbox from Gridview ?